# Getting values from multiple tables with a single INNER JOIN like query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a simple Hangman game in Django. I have two models, one for the list of words and one for the games played by users, with a foreign key relationship defined between them. This is the model definition:

```
class WordMaster(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField("Secret Word", max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField("Category", max_length=20)
    sub_category = models.CharField("Sub-category", max_length=50)

class GamesPlayed(models.Model):
    word_id = models.ForeignKey(WordMaster, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    guessed_letters = models.CharField("Guessed letters", max_length=72, null=True)
    guesses = models.IntegerField("Number of guesses", null=True)
    won = models.BooleanField("Won", null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField("Started", auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
```

Now when the game is being played, I need the word along with the guessed letters and number of guesses.

I would do this using pure SQL as follows:

```
SELECT * from gamesplayed gp
    JOIN wordmaster wm on gp.word_id = wm.id
    where gp.id = 5
```

However, I have failed to find an equivalent query in Django ORM despite looking in many places.

So I finally used a filter query and got the results of one in a dictionary, then updated the dictionary to add the values from the other table. Here's the code I used:

```
g = GamesPlayed.objects.filter(pk=5)
game = list(g.values())[0]
game.update(list(WordMaster.objects.filter(pk=game['word_id_id']).values())[0])
```

But this seems like a rather redundant way of doing things for two reasons:

1. I am not able to use the relationship defined in the model
2. If I have 3-4 tables so related, then I'll have to make the queries one by one for each table, completely defeating the purpose of the ORM.

So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest renaming your field `word_id = models.ForeignKey(WordMaster, ...)` to `word_master`, so that the semantics look nicer/more understandable. In your current code you have to do `gp.word_id.word` (and `word_id` is misleading because it actually is a related object and not just an ID) and after renaming the field you would do `gp.word_master.word` (conveing more clearly that it is a related object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but I think you might need to use [`.select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

I used the example of the docs, applied to your case

> Here’s standard lookup:
>
> ```
> # Hits the database.
> gp = GamesPlayed.objects.get(id=5)
>
> # Hits the database again to get the related `WordMaster` object.
> word_to_guess = gp.word_id.word
> ```
>
> And here’s select_related lookup:
>
> ```
> # Hits the database.
> gp = GamesPlayed.objects.select_related('word_id').get(id=5)
>
> # Doesn't hit the database, because `gp.word_id` has been
> # prepopulated in the previous query.
> word_to_guess = gp.word_id.word
> ```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Any way to get all the values in a single dictionary?

Comment: @gouravkr could you elaborate on what values you wish to have in a dictionary. And what would be the keys of that dict?

Comment: Since I'm specifying a single id, it will always return just one row. So I want to convert all the values from both the tables into a dict, with the model field names as the keys. But I think I can live without this part now, as I understood the structure of the queryset and was able to complete my usecase without the dict.